# Laravel Eloquent doesn't update only inserting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am facing some problems with PHP Laravel update function. It doesn't update, only insert.

```
 public function post_rate(){
    $o = Input::all();

    //has user already rated?!
    $query = DB::table("ratings")->select("id")->where("user", "=", Auth::user()->id)->where("story_id", "=", $o['story_id'])->get();
    foreach ( $query as $d):
        $theID = $d->id;
    endforeach;
    if ( empty($query)):  //User hasn't rated!
           $z = new Rating(); 
    else: 
          $z = new Rating($theID);  //user has rated, tell which to update  
-----------------------------^ that cause the problem!
     endif;

        $z->story_id = $o['story_id'];
        $z->user = Auth::user()->id;
        $z->rating = $o['rating'];
        $z->save();

         echo "OK";

}
```

It works when no rows founded, but when i will use new Rating(@something) it fails.

the column id in "ratings" table is primary and auto_increment.

In my model i have also set up

```
 public static $key = 'id';
```

The output "$theID" also contains the correctly ID for the mysql row.

Comment: Piece of advice -if you want to get an array containing the values from only one column, you can do it this way:
$idArray = DB::table("ratings")->where("user", "=", Auth::user()->id)->where("story_id", "=", $o['story_id'])->lists('id');

Answer (score 3):

Try: `$z = Rating::find($theID)` with `->first()` or `->get()` instead

Answer (score 2):

```
$z = Rating::find($theID);
```

or

```
$z = Rating::where('id', '=', $theID)->first();
```

Both are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

In order to update in laravel simply use the command

```
Rating::where('id','=',$theID)->update(array('name'=> $name));
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Answer (score 2):

The dude !

I was taking the same problem. Checking out the source code, I found that the correct field to set the primary key name is 'primarykey'.

For example:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take it **easy** ! 

take a look at this , when user hasn't rated you just save it as you did before !

```
if ( empty($query)){  //User hasn't rated!
        $z = new Rating();    
        $z->story_id = $o['story_id'];
        $z->user = Auth::user()->id;
        $z->rating = $o['rating'];
        $z->save();
}
```

and in the **update** part ! do as follows :

```
 else{
    $rates = array(
                'story_id' => $o['story_id'],
                'user' => Auth::user()->id,
                'rating' => $o['rating'],
            );
$old = Rating::find($theID);
$old->fill($rates);
$old->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For registration, Eloquent was not running the update because the method I used (see below) did not set the exists attribute to true. This is because I was getting all the fields returned ($ request-> all) from the request and creating a model, but that does not enable the object to update.

**This did not work**

```
$produto = new Produto($request->all());
$produto->update();
```

**This also did not work**

```
$produto = new Produto($request->all());

$produtoToUpdate = Produto::find($this->id);
$produtoToUpdate->update(get_object_vars($produto));
```

> Never use **get_object_var**, Eloquent Model has virtual attribute (you get with getAttributes), so **get_object_var** did not return your fields.

**This work!!**

```
$produto = new Produto($request->all());

if ($this->id <= 0 )
{
    $produto->save();
} else
{
    $produto->exists = true;
    $produto->id = $this->id;
    $produto->update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem, so it turns out to be eloquent model issue.

First of all add a protected array name fillable in your model and define the attributes.Like

```
protected $fillable = array('story_id', 'rating');
```

There are many way to update table in Laravel in your case.

```
1. $requestedRating = Rating::findOrFail($id)->first()->update($request->all()); // No need for first if the id is unique.

2.  $requestedRating = Rating::findOrFail($id)->get()->update($request->all()); // fetch records from that model and update.

3. $requestedRating = Rating::whereIn('id', $id)->update($request->all());
```

In place of update you can also use fill like.

```
1. $requestedRating = Rating::findOrFail($id)->first()->fill($request->all())->save();
```

There is always DB::table method but use this only when no option is available.